# python shorten multiple nested loops in Grasshopper

Tags: python, iterator, generator, grasshopper, rhino3d

I can't yet find a way to solve this problem without using multiple nested loops. The issue is that I'm doing a comparison between two lists using a geometric method from Rhinoceros. Basically there's a list of lines, a set of start and end points (nested lists). All of the start and end points are touching the lines. The script compares the index of the closest line to the start with the closest line to the end, and if they match it returns `True`.

This is my current code:

```
for i in range (10):
    for j in range (100):
        for k in range (3):
            for l in range (len(linesList)):
                pullSt = rc.Geometry.Curve.ClosestPoint(linesList[l], stPoint[i][j][k], 0.0001)[0]
                pullEnd = rc.Geometry.Curve.ClosestPoint(linesList[l], endPoint[i][j][k], 0.0001)[0]
                if pullSt == True and pullEnd == True:
                    match[i][j][k] = True
```

I thought it might work with a generator expression, but I got stuck because it seems like I actually have to temporarily store the the pullSt and pullEnd values before comparing with each other. I know I'm probably overloading my memory and there must be a faster way of doing this, but I'm just not sure how.

NOTE: rc.Geometry.Curve.ClosestPoint returns `True` if the distance between the line and the point is less than the tolerance of 0.0001, meaning the point is on the line.

Comment: Are you just hoping to have fewer nested loops? There's itertools.product that would give you an equivalent iterator with `itertools.product(range(10),range(100), range(3))`

Comment: I think either itertools product or a generator function might work, but I don't know how to integrate the important part of the script in there. The bit about pullSt, pullEnd, etc.

Comment: You'd keep that bit the same. `for i, j, k in itertools.product(...)` and then the innermost part of your loop. Am I understanding what you're asking properly?

One thing you are doing that's extraneous is continuing to check lines after you've found the one you need. I might collapse the first three loops using itertools and then keep the inner loop so you can break out of it when you find the right line.

The memory of the `pullSt` and `pullEnd` is negligible. You're only keeping them around for one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This looping doesn't seem to reference anything else in your data set, and as such would probably be OK as a much shorter bit of code working on each object by using grasshopper's own inbuilt tooling.

```
pullSt = rc.Geometry.Curve.ClosestPoint(linesList[l], stPoint, 0.0001)[0]
pullEnd = rc.Geometry.Curve.ClosestPoint(linesList[l], endPoint, 0.0001)[0]
if pullSt == True and pullEnd == True:
    match = True
```

If you right click on the inputs you can change them from tree access to item access.

This is all a guess though because you haven't said what problem you are actually trying to solve.

If you post the problem I'll update the answer to be more specific.